# How can I route "/img/" to the "/Content/img" folder in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I want all the urls for my images in my ASP.NET MVC application to be of the form:

www.mydomain.com/img/someimagename.png

However, I currently have all my images in my MVC project in the:
/Content/img/ folder.

How can I write a route that will map /img to /Content/img?

Comment: a route won't suffice. Routes are just mappings between URLs and action methods.

Comment: why not just put all your images in an `img` directory?

Comment: @BuildStarted I am running into this situation as well...I don't really want "Content" in urls, but putting it on the root pollutes the project. But I suppose that's what I got to live with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Images don't pass through the ASP.NET stack.  IIS handles those requests.  You need to write an HttpModule if you want your ASP.NET application to handle image requests.  This blog shows you how to do this: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgaylord/archive/2009/05/04/letting-asp-net-handle-image-file-extensions-in-iis-6.aspx

But an easier solution would be to just create a virtual directory in IIS.

Comment: @Anuraj  Its outdated now but you can still see a snapshot of the page here http://web.archive.org/web/20121102165326/http://weblogs.asp.net/jgaylord/archive/2009/05/04/letting-asp-net-handle-image-file-extensions-in-iis-6.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can use rewrite rules for this. Add following route to rewrite section in  web.config:

```
<rule name="Img to content img">
 <match url="^img/(.*)" />
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/Content/img/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 2):

what about this approach,

```
 public ActionResult Img(string imgURL)
    {
        ViewBag.imageURL = imgURL;
        return View();
    }
```

and the razor view

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/"+@ViewBag.imageURL)" />
```

or in a basic asp.net view

```
 <img src="~/Content/images/"+ViewBag.imageURL)" />
```